# Error related to Reanimated Plug in + React Native + Visual Studio Code

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-drawer

`Hi,

I am working Drawer plug-in in React Native..., Now got stucked with below errors. Added all necessary entries in babel.config.js and even tried reinstalling reanimated-plug in.

[Reanimated] The native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized. This could be caused by

- not rebuilding the app after installing or upgrading Reanimated

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'installCoreFunctions' of undefined, js engine: hermes
LOG  Running "Hello_World" with {"rootTag":11}

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "Hello_World" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it
  in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

- **Babel.config.js entries also copied below which seems to be correct...,
- **
  presets:['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],

Please guide to resolve the issue`

Comment: Hi. For which platform are you developing? Reanimated currently does not support Windows.
I am sure you tried npm start -- --reset-cache already?